# calculating entropy of binary data (from strings)

Tags: java, math, statistics, probability, entropy

I'm trying to wrap my head around entropy. I basically understand this:

> Technically, entropy is the sum over all events of the probability of each event times the log probability of that event.
> If you consider a 8-bit byte, if all 256 values are equally likely, then the byte contains 8 bits of entropy or equivalently, 8 bits of real information. If some bit patterns are more likely than others, for example the bit pattern for the letter ‘e’, then the byte will contain less than 8 bits of entropy or information.
> Running English text is pretty low entropy, at about 2.3 bits per byte. This is why compression algorithms work well on text files.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-entropy-in-terms-of-cryptography

For now let's say I'm using strings of ASCII converted into string arrays of binary, as in

```
// [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
// [1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1]
// [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
// [0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1]
```

I've devised 2 methods for calculating entropy (maybe they are both wrong, I don't know). The first is to start with the element[1] and compare each bit to element[0] and element[2], and for each bit they share in the same location, add 1 to a running score. I then divide by 2. I end up with something that is consistent-ish with the 2.3 bytes of entropy as described above. As in, the score for most of my text is that they share 5-6~ bits with their neighbors on average.

The other method is to just add up each 'column' of bits and then average them to find a probability of their appearance. For the above I get

```
//=[2 1 4 4 0 0 3 3] / 4 = [.5 .25 1 1 0 0 .75 .75] as probabilities
```

For the above, I am less sure how to derive an entropy 'score.

In any case, I'm curious if people can help me to understand if I am doing this right, or more likely, how I can improve or understand this differently.

Thank you

Comment: First you provide a definition of entropy, then you don't use it all. Are you trying to verify that the english text has about 2.3 bits of entropy per character?

Comment: I think I follow the definition "the sum over all events of the probability of each event" in calculating the probabilities for each bit being a 1 or 0 in a given data set. It would be a coincidence if I arrived at the same entropy for English text otherwise no?